# Difference between two branches of $D^0$ decay

Tags: particle-physics, elementary-particles

I'm trying to understand the following decays:

i) $D^0 \rightarrow K^- + \pi^+$

ii) $D^0 \rightarrow K^+ + \pi^-$

The question came from Griffiths' "Introduction to Elementary Particles", chapter 2.

Well, both have the same quark content: $c\bar{u} \rightarrow u\bar{s}+u\bar{d}$, however, the resulting branching ratios are not equal! I do not understand the answer given in the solutions manual for this.

Question: Why on first case the c quark was transformed into $\pi^+$ and s quark but on the second it became $K^+$ and a d quark?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A $W^+$ boson carries a positive charge. Since $W$ bosons mediate weak interactions, in this specific case weak interactions of quarks, is well known that they induce, in the quark sector, a flavour change. This flavour change is between the up quarks $(u,c,t)$ and the down quarks $(d,s,b)$. In particular the $W^+$ changes up quarks to down quarks since the up quarks carry charge $+2/3$ and the down quarks carry a charge $-1/3$ in units of $e$. The difference between them is a positive unit of charge.

So in this specific case you can change the $c$ in the $D^0$ to a $d$ or $s$ quarks. The top quark is all another story. So wether the charm quark transforms to a down or strange changes the final result. In one case there will be a $K^-$ and in the other a $\pi^-$.

Now the $W^+$ boson will become a meson (at tree level). In this case we're studying the two decays in a $K^+$ or $\pi^+$.

As to *why* the two diagrams have a different branching ratio is encoded in the CKM matrix elements that enter the decay. In fact we have that

$$D^0\rightarrow K^-\,\pi^+\implies |A|^2\propto |V_{cs}||V_{ud}|\\
D^0\rightarrow K^+\,\pi^-\implies |A|^2\propto |V_{cd}||V_{us}|$$ All the other quantities are exactly the same. Which means that

$$\frac{\sigma(D^0\rightarrow K^-\,\pi^+)}{\sigma(D^0\rightarrow K^+\,\pi^-)}=\frac{|V_{cs}||V_{ud}|}{|V_{cd}||V_{us}|}$$

You can easily see from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabibbo%E2%80%93Kobayashi%E2%80%93Maskawa_matrix) that the experimental values of that CKM matrix elements are different and so the branching ratios have to be different.